# How to Refresh list view in android

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I am creating an android application that consists of a list view populated by the data from the database.

Here I need to delete the data from the database as well as the list view and refresh the list view.

I used both `notifyOnDataSetChanged()` and `notifyOnDataSetInvalidated()` but

it wont work for me please help me with this

```
package com.developer.milanandroid;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gc.materialdesign.widgets.Dialog;
import com.milan.emptylayout.EmptyLayout;
import com.milan.lib.progressgenarator.lib.ProgressGenerator;
import com.milan.lib.progressgenarator.lib.ProgressGenerator.OnCompleteListener;
import com.milan.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenu;
import com.milan.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuCreator;
import com.milan.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuItem;
import com.milan.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView;
import com.milan.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import com.processbutton.lib.milan.ActionProcessButton;

public class DatabaseListView extends Activity implements OnCompleteListener {
    MediaPlayer media_player;
    ActionProcessButton fetch_database;
    SwipeMenuListView database_results;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter logindatabase_adapter;
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursoradapter;
    Cursor cursor;
    TextView username_txt,password_txt;
    String user_name_string,password_string;
    String text;
    Dialog dialog;
    private EmptyLayout empty_layout;
    View.OnClickListener emptyClickListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.databaselistview);

        View.OnClickListener mErrorClickListener = new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    fetch_database.setText("Checking...");
                    empty_layout.showLoading();
                    ProgressGenerator pg = new ProgressGenerator(DatabaseListView.this);
                    pg.start(fetch_database);


            }
        };

        emptyClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(DatabaseListView.this, "Try again button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };

        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.hide();
        View v;

        LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        username_txt = (TextView)linear.getChildAt(0);
        password_txt = (TextView)linear.getChildAt(0);
        user_name_string = username_txt.getText().toString();
        password_string = password_txt.getText().toString();
        fetch_database = (ActionProcessButton)findViewById(R.id.Button_Fetch_from_Database);
        database_results = (SwipeMenuListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_database);
        final ProgressGenerator progressGenerator = new ProgressGenerator(DatabaseListView.this);
        logindatabase_adapter = new LoginDataBaseAdapter(DatabaseListView.this);

        empty_layout = new EmptyLayout(DatabaseListView.this, database_results);
        empty_layout.setErrorButtonClickListener(mErrorClickListener);

        fetch_database.setMode(ActionProcessButton.Mode.PROGRESS);
        fetch_database.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                progressGenerator.start(fetch_database);
                fetch_database.setText("Checking...");
                fetch_database.setEnabled(false);
                empty_layout.showLoading();
                media_player = MediaPlayer.create(DatabaseListView.this, R.raw.retrievingfromdatabase);
                media_player.start();

                String[] from = {LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_NAME,LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_PASSWORD};
                int[] to = {R.id.txt_username,R.id.txt_pasword};
                cursor = logindatabase_adapter.feching_Data();
                cursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DatabaseListView.this, R.layout.listcell, cursor, from, to);
                cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //registerForContextMenu(database_results);





            }
        });


        SwipeMenuCreator swipe_list_view = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

            @Override
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {

                SwipeMenuItem open_swipemenu = new SwipeMenuItem(DatabaseListView.this);
                open_swipemenu.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0x9B,0x33,0xF0)));
                open_swipemenu.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                open_swipemenu.setIcon(R.drawable.databasedelete);
                menu.addMenuItem(open_swipemenu);
            }
        };

        database_results.setMenuCreator(swipe_list_view);
        database_results.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(final int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {

            switch(index)   {
            case 0:

                dialog = new Dialog(DatabaseListView.this, "Delete Record", "Do you want to delete Record from database");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setOnAcceptButtonClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        cursor  = (Cursor) database_results.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoginDataBaseAdapter.ID));
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_NAME));
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_PASSWORD));
                        logindatabase_adapter.deleteEntry(item_id);
                        //database_results.removeViewAt(position);
                        //cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        database_results.invalidateViews();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();      

            }

                return false;
            }

        });


    }

    protected int dp2px(int dp) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.database_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
        database_results.setAdapter(cursoradapter);
        fetch_database.setEnabled(false);
        fetch_database.setText("SUCCESS");
        }
        else{
            /*fetch_database.setEnabled(false);
            fetch_database.setText("OOPS");
            fetch_database.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb74d"));
            final Dialog dialog_database = new Dialog(DatabaseListView.this, "Database Records", "No Records was found in the database");
                                    dialog_database.setOnAcceptButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            dialog_database.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    dialog_database.show();*/
            fetch_database.setText("OOPS");
            fetch_database.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb74d"));
            empty_layout.showError();



        }


    }


    }
```

This is my LoginDatabase adpater:

```
package com.developer.milanandroid;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;

public class LoginDataBaseAdapter 
{
        //Database name
        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MilanloginRegistration.db";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
        // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
        // SQL Statement to create a new database.
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="MilanLoginregistration";
        public static final String ID="_id";
        public static final String USER_NAME="USERNAME";
        public static final String USER_PASSWORD ="PASSWORD";


        static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+ TABLE_NAME +
                                     "( " +ID+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+"USERNAME text not null,"+USER_PASSWORD+" text not null); ";
        // Variable to hold the database instance
        public  SQLiteDatabase db;
        // Context of the application using the database.
        private final Context context;
        // Database open/upgrade helper
        private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter(Context _context) 
        {
            context = _context;
            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
        {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public void close() 
        {
            db.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return db;
        }
        public LoginDataBaseAdapter opentoRead() throws android.database.SQLException{

            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        public LoginDataBaseAdapter opentoWrite() throws android.database.SQLException{

            dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void Close(){
            dbHelper.close();
        }


        public void insertEntry(String username,String password)
        {
           ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

            newValues.put("USERNAME",username);
            newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert("MilanLoginregistration",null,newValues);
            ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        public int deleteAll(){
            return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        }

        public void deleteEntry(int id){
            //String id=String.valueOf(ID);
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID+"="+id, null);
           // Toast.makeText(context, "Number fo Entry Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        public Cursor queue_all(){
            String[] columns = new String[]{ID,"USERNAME","PASSWORD"};
            Cursor cursor_queue_all =db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            return cursor_queue_all;
        }

        public Cursor feching_Data(){

            String[] columns = {ID,USER_NAME,USER_PASSWORD};
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,null,null,null,null,null);
            return cursor;

        }
        public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("MilanLoginregistration", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
            //cursor.close();
            return password;                
        }
        public String checkSinlgeEntry(String userName)
        {
            Cursor cursor=db.query("MilanLoginregistration", null, " USERNAME=?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount()>=1) // UserName  Exist
            {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
           // cursor.close();
            return "";              
        }
        public void  updateEntry(String user_name,String pasword)
        {
            // Define the updated row content.
            ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.  
            updatedValues.put("USERNAME", user_name);
            updatedValues.put("PASSWORD",pasword);


            String where="USERNAME = ?";
            db.update("MilanLoginregistration",updatedValues, where, new String[]{user_name});             
        }   
        /*public void Display(View v){
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from MilanloginRegistration", null);
            admin_settings_child.text_fetched_database_results.setText("");
            c.moveToFirst();
            do{
                String username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("USERNAME"));
                String password = c.getString(1);
                admin_settings_child.text_fetched_database_results.append("USERNAME::-->"+username+"PASSWORD::-->"+password+"\n");

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: What does your cursoradapter look like?

Comment: This was to fetch the data from database and put into the listview like this: cursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DatabaseListView.this, R.layout.listcell, cursor, from, to);
    cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();@BidhanA

Comment: after deleting data from the database, delete the data from the list too. after doing these steps you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of adapter to refresh the list.

Comment: I did for the cursor adapter for the above dude @ShifarShifz

Comment: how do you create your CursorAdapter?

Comment: cursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DatabaseListView.this, R.layout.listcell, cursor, from, to); @pskink

Comment: are you sure that logindatabase_adapter.deleteEntry() deletes anything?

Comment: yes. it deletes database dude @pskink

Comment: what are you doing with: `Runnable run` ? it is not used anywhere... what is `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_NAME));` for? i think you dont know what you are doing in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Kindly post the code of your adapter as well. in the above code you are deleting the data from other adapter and notifying other adapter for data set changed. i.e in following lines I can't see where cursoradapter is actually being updated.

```
logindatabase_adapter.deleteEntry(item_id);
cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
cursoradapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
```

also you can try this.

```
listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

For proper implementing datasetchanged functionality you need to create custom adapter other wise you just setlist adapter every time your data is being changed.i.e

```
listeview.setAdapter(modifiedAdapter);
listview.getAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Edit 1:

as you are using simple cursor adapter you need to add following lines after deleting the entry:

```
logindatabase_adapter.deleteEntry(item_id);
cursor = logindatabase_adapter.feching_Data();
//database_results.removeViewAt(position);
cursoradapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(DatabaseListView.this,   R.layout.listcell, cursor, from, to);
database_results.setAdapter(cursoradapter);
database_results.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I posted my whole main activity and LoginDatabase adapter dude @M.J

Comment: oh sorry ok let me check.

Comment: As you were no where giving newly data to the cursor adapter it wasn't updating. hope fully this will work .

Answer (score -1):

Use the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the adapter like this:

```
final ArrayAdapter adapter = ((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter());
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: No idea if the above is a valid answer, but a few more words would be nice (e.g. an example how and where to use the method)